# vb.net keypress event between 2 solutions (visual studio 2010)

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm new in Vb and please guide me on below matter:

There are 2 different forms from different Solution (Eg: SolutionA\Form1 and SolutionB\Form2).

Both forms have multiple textboxes.

First we input data in a textbox in SolutionA\Form1. Then, by using KeyPress event, the cursor move to textbox in SolutionB\Form2.

After that, by using Keypress event in SolutionB\Form2, the cursor move back to another textbox in SolutionA\Form1.

Is it possible to dot this way? If it possible, please let me know how to do the coding. I'm using Visual Studio 2010. Thanks.

---

I've created a test form (Form 1) with a textbox named txtPart.

Once I hit button "Enter", I want the data from txtPart to be transferred to Notepad. 
How can I call class NotepadSendAndReceive from here?

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub txtPart_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtPart.KeyPress

        Try
            If e.KeyChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then
                ' How to call NotepadSendAndReceive class here?
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Kindly please help. Thank you.

================================================================================

I've created a test form (Form 1) with a textbox named txtPart.

Once I hit button "Enter", I want the data from txtPart to be transferred to Notepad. How can I call class NotepadSendAndReceive from here?
Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub txtPart_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtPart.KeyPress

    Try
        If e.KeyChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then
            ' How to call NotepadSendAndReceive class here?
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

Kindly please help. Thank you.

Comment: do you have a `Form2.TextBox1.Focus()` in your KeyPress Event?

Comment: No because I'm not sure how to put Focus() to form in different solution. However I always use that way if in both forms in same solution.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by using NamedPipeServer (high complexity) or
otherwise by using WinApi (I would recommend this).

Have a look at this:

```
Public Class NotepadSendAndReceive
        Public Const VK_RETURN As UInteger = &HD
        Public Const WM_SETFOCUS As UInteger = &H7
        Public Const WM_KILLFOCUS As UInteger = &H8
        Public Const WM_CHAR As UInteger = &H102
        Public Const WM_SETTEXT As UInteger = &HC
        Public Const WM_KEYDOWN As UInteger = &H100
        Public Const WM_KEYUP As UInteger = &H101
        Public Const cap As Integer = 1048576
        Public Const WM_CLICK As UInteger = &HF5
        Public Const WM_GETTEXT As UInteger = &HD
        Public Const WM_GETTEXTLENGTH As UInteger = &HE

        <DllImport("User32.Dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> Private Shared Function GetWindowTextLength(hWnd As IntPtr) As Integer
        End Function
        <DllImport("User32.Dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> Private Shared Function GetWindowText(hWnd As IntPtr, lpString As StringBuilder, nMaxCount As Integer) As Integer
        End Function
        <DllImport("User32.Dll")> Private Shared Function SendMessage(hWnd As IntPtr, Msg As UInt32, wParam As IntPtr, lParam As String) As IntPtr
        End Function
        <DllImport("User32.Dll")> Private Shared Function SendMessage(hWnd As IntPtr, Msg As Integer, wParam As Integer, lParam As StringBuilder) As Integer
        End Function
        <DllImport("User32.Dll")> Public Shared Function PostMessage(hWnd As Integer, msg As UInteger, wParam As UInteger, lParam As Integer) As IntPtr
        End Function
        <DllImport("User32.Dll")> Public Shared Function PostMessage(hWnd As Integer, msg As UInteger, wParam As UInteger, lParam As UInteger) As IntPtr
        End Function
        <DllImport("User32.Dll")> Private Shared Function FindWindow(lpClassName As String, lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
        End Function
        <DllImport("User32.Dll")> Private Shared Function FindWindowEx(parentHandle As IntPtr, childAfter As IntPtr, className As String, windowTitle As IntPtr) As IntPtr
        End Function

        Private Shared Function GetStringOfEditor() As String
            Return GetText(GetProcNumber("Editor"))
        End Function

        Public Shared Sub SendStringToEditor(T As String)
            SendMessage(GetProcNumber("Editor"), &HC, CType(cap, IntPtr), T)
        End Sub

        Public Shared Sub SendEnter(Hwndd As IntPtr)
            SendMessage(Hwndd, WM_SETFOCUS, CType(cap, IntPtr), String.Empty)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
            PostMessage(Hwndd.ToInt32(), WM_KEYDOWN, &HD, &H1C0001)
            PostMessage(Hwndd.ToInt32(), WM_CHAR, &HD, &H1C0001)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
            PostMessage(Hwndd.ToInt32(), WM_KEYUP, &HD, &HC01C0001UI)
            SendMessage(Hwndd, WM_KILLFOCUS, CType(cap, IntPtr), String.Empty)
        End Sub

        Private Shared Function GetProcNumber(pTitle As String) As IntPtr
            Dim Pzs As New List(Of String)
            For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses
                If p.MainWindowTitle.Contains(pTitle) Then Pzs.Add(p.MainWindowTitle)
            Next
            If Pzs.Count > 0 Then Return FindWindowEx(FindWindow("Notepad", Pzs(0)), IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", IntPtr.Zero)
        End Function

        Private Shared Function GetText(hWnd As IntPtr) As String
            Dim nLen As Integer = CInt(SendMessage(hWnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, IntPtr.Zero, String.Empty))
            Dim pText As New StringBuilder(nLen + 1)
            SendMessage(hWnd, WM_GETTEXT, nLen + 1, pText)
            Return pText.ToString()
        End Function

    End Class
```

Calling example (Notepad has to be opened)

```
   NotepadSendAndReceive.SendStringToEditor("This is a test")
```

You just have to customise this a little bit, you just have
to find out the current handle for your textbox.

Take a look at :

```
  If Pzs.Count > 0 Then Return FindWindowEx(FindWindow("Notepad", Pzs(0)), IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", IntPtr.Zero)
```

The program seeks for the current handle of "Notepad" and then the subhandle of the "Edit" element by using "FindWindowEx".

Then you have the right current handle for your notepad editing area and you can for instance send text to it.

In your case it would be "Form2" and then you have to know how your textbox is named (this can be found out by using WinSpy++).

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks Sir SiriSch! I'll study this method and try to do the coding. I've searching in many forums but never find about this idea before. Thanks again :)